# Java Selection sort

Tags: java, sorting, selection

```
A - an array containing the list of numbers
numItems - the number of numbers in the list

for i = 0 to numItems - 1
    for  j = i+1 to numItems 
        if A[i] > A[j]
            // Swap the entries
            Temp = A[i]
            A[i] = A[j]
            A[j] = Temp  
        End If    
    Next j
Next i\
```

Can comeone convert this to java for me?
I've tried but can't figure it out.

Comment: You're pretty close anyways...should be easy enough to look up...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852522/selection-sort-for-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static void selectionSort1(int[] x) {
    for (int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<x.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] > x[j]) {
                // Exchange elements
                int temp = x[i];
                x[i] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```